# Cocoa Touch framework shared between iOS and tvOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xcode7, tvos

I'm working on an app that can have some shared code that I want to encapsulate in a framework. I created iOS `Putter` app target, then a framework `PutterKit` that I link from the app. This works fine.

Then I create a tvOS app target `PutterTV` and duplicate the `PutterKit` to `PutterKit (TV)` and set its sdk to `tvOS`

[image]

When I `import PutterKit` in the tvOS app and compile it, I get the error 

`No such module 'PutterKit'`

Here is a sample project 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1326174/Putter.zip

What is the correct way to setup such a framework?

Comment: Your sample project is currently a photo of a bicycle.

Comment: sorry, wrong link :) Updated

Comment: I've struggled a lot with this as well. Can't find any way to do this—which seems like an obvious need when you have two so similar platforms like tvOS and iOS. Weird.

Comment: I think a solution could be to have the framework as separate project and integrate it via either CocoaPods or Carthage

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your project, you need to:

```
import PutterTVKit
```

If you look at your PutterKit(TV) target build settings, you will notice that the ProductName and ProductModuleName are PutterTVKit.

Also make sure that in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section in PutterTV app target, you link in PutterTVKit.framework (not PutterKit.framework).

With these changes, it appears to compile fine.

Comment: But what if I have a view controller in my app that is also shared between iOS and tvOS (which I do)

Comment: You can certainly share the view controller class between iOS and tvOS - just make it a member of both targets, but considering how drastically different the UI modeling is for iOS and tvOS, the recommendation would be to have separate UIs, while sharing the same view controller for logic...

Comment: What I meant is that if I have a shared view controller, I'd have to import both `PutterKit` and `PutterTVKit ` which is not a best solution. It should be possible to build just one `PutterKit ` for both `iOS` and `tvOS` and import it only once. Basically I want to achieve what Carthage would do if I was building a 3rd party library with it.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to build one framework (PutterKit) for iOS and tvOS. The only possible solution for your scenario is to #ifdef and import the correct framework on top - using a build setting in your app targets for iOS and tvOS, or rely on TARGET_OS_TV